# my media player playlist duplicates only one song in the list view in android studio below is my playlist codes

Tags: java, android, listview

My media player playlist duplicates only one song in the list view  in android studio below is my playlist codes

```
    //init vars

    ListView songview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);

    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    getSongList();

    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
        public int compare(Song a, Song b ){
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });
    SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
    songview.setAdapter(songAdt);
}

public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve Song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor !=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

This is my playlist java class, I have five songs in my **SD Card** and I use an emulator to run my app but my playlist detects only one song and displays it five times in the `ListView`. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Did you give necessary permissions to access external storage?

Comment: yes ,thanks its been solved it was a misuse of variable in my songadapter class